# Splitting a complicated (?) string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I got this string :

```
my.song.mp3 greatSong.flac not3.txt video.mp4 game.exe mov!e.mkv
```

I need to split the file name from file type.

How do I do it considering '.' is problematic as in the .mp3 file?

Comment: Please specify your requirements. What exactly you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim it from the last occurrence of '.' in the string.

```js
let fileName = "my.song.mp3";

fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."))

console.log(fileName)
```

**EDIT:** Just realised you probably meant that was one large string and you need to return an array of the file names? Is that right? If so this will work:

```js
let initialString = "my.song.mp3 greatSong.flac not3.txt video.mp4 game.exe mov!e.mkv";

let fileNames = initialString.split(" ");

fileNames = fileNames.map(fileName => fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));

console.log(fileNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test()
{
   try 
   {
      // start with initial data
      var theExample = "my.song.mp3 greatSong.flac not3.txt video.mp4 game.exe mov!e.mkv" ;

      // split in individual file names by splitting string on whitespace
      var fileNames = theExample.split(/\s/) ;

      // run over each fileName
      var i = fileNames.length ;
      while (i-- > 0)
      {
         // remove literal dot and trailing word characters at the end of the string; show result
         alert( fileNames[i].replace(/\.[\w]+$/,"") ) ;
      }
   }
   catch(err) 
   {
      // show error message
      alert(err.message);
   }
}
```